# Haskell, how to use show function

Tags: haskell

```
type Start = String
type Destination = String
type Distance = Float         -- km
type AverageSpeed = Float   -- m/s 
type FirstClass = Bool

data Trip = Trip Start [TravelOption]
data TravelOption = Plane AverageSpeed Destination Distance FirstClass | Bus AverageSpeed Destination Distance | Train AverageSpeed Destination Distance FirstClass

class VacationTrip a 
  where 

instance Show TravelOption
where
show (Plane speed dest distance firstClass) = " by plane to " ++ dest
show (Bus speed dest distance) = " by bus to " ++ dest
show (Train speed dest distance firstClass) = "by train to " ++ dest

instance Show Trip
where
show (Trip start travelOptions) = "[" ++ start ++ "]" ++ formatList (map show travelOptions)
where
formatList :: [String] -> String
formatList [] = ""
formatList [x] = "[" ++ x ++ "]"
formatList (x:xs) = "(" ++ x ++ ") " ++ formatList xs
```

How should i change my show or formatList function, so i get the output, which i need?
I need an output like this;

[Start] by plane to (next City) by train to (next City by train to [last City].

Cities should be in brackets (last one must be in square bracket)

What i get with my code is like;
[Amsterdam] (by plane to Berlin) (by train to Paris) [by train to Cologne]

I hope, i could explain my Problem...

Comment: can you share the data types?

Comment: `code`type Start = String
type Destination = String
type Distance = Float         -- km
type AverageSpeed = Float   -- m/s 
type FirstClass = Bool

data Trip = Trip Start [TravelOption]
data TravelOption = Plane AverageSpeed Destination Distance FirstClass | Bus AverageSpeed Destination Distance | Train AverageSpeed Destination Distance FirstClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first create a parameterized variant of your `show` function that determines how to format the city:

```
showWith :: (String -> String) -> TravelOption -> String
showWith f = go
  where
    go (Plane speed dest distance firstClass) = " by plane to " ++ f dest
    go (Bus speed dest distance) = " by bus to " ++ f dest
    go (Train speed dest distance firstClass) = "by train to " ++ f dest

instance Show TravelOption where
  show = showWith id
```

then we can use this to format the sequence:

```
squareBrackets :: String -> String
squareBrackets x = '[' : x ++ "]"

parenthesis :: String -> String
parenthesis x = '(' : x ++ ")"

instance Show Trip where
  show (Trip start travelOptions) = squareBrackets start ++ formatList travelOptions
    where
      formatList [] = ""
      formatList [x] = ' ' : showWith squareBrackets x
      formatList (x : xs) = ' ' : showWith parenthesis x ++ formatList xs
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help. I have been trying to solve this problem since like 7 Hours. I have one more question. Here parenthesis x = '(' : x ++ ")" why is left parenthesis Char, but right one is String? Can i write it like that parenthesis x = "(" ++ x ++ ")"?

Comment: @AdnanErenGüngörmüş: yes, the two are equivalent.

Comment: I didn't understand show = showWith id exactly. Why did you implement it like this. Do we calling here simply showWith function and is "id" have a meaning here? I am sorry, i am new with classes and instances. I am still trying to understand

Comment: @AdnanErenGüngörmüş `id` is the identity function, effectively turning `f dest` into `id dest` and so to just `dest`. In this context, it's the "don't add parentheses/brackets" function.